# Regex: match text square brackets and what is contained within square brackets then search and replace

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I am trying to match (a) and replace (b) the following occurrences:

```
array[0] -> atoi(array[0])
array[1] -> atoi(array[1])
...
array[i+1] -> atoi(array[i+1])
```

and so on...

(a) I am unable to match anything with the following expression `array\\[(.\*?)\\]` , `array\\[.\*?\\]` , or `array\\[*\\]`

I am able to match single character occurrences between the brackets with `array\\[.\\]` and additionally also segments with multiples matches on a single line with `array\\[.*\\]`

(b) After a working match I figure `s/"MATCHING REGEX"/atoi(array\[\1\])/g` should work, however attempting that with `array\\[.\\]` resulted in `atoi(array[])`

Comment: If you have code sections in your question, you can use CTRL-K or the toolbar button to format them properly. No need to put weird double quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
:s/\<array\[[^\]]\+\]/atoi(\0)/
```

Comment: Thanks ":s/array\\[\d\\]/atoi(\0)/" works for replacing all the references with numbers correctly. Ex: array[0] -> atoi(array[0])

However, I am still unable to match other indices within the brackets

Comment: That works beautifully, it works with and without the prefixed "\<". Can you explain that as well as the reg ex goodness?

I understand it as "\\[" beginning bracket, [^\\]] anything but the ], \+ one or more occurrences (why do you escape this?), and "\\]" the closing bracket. Replace with text and match inserted

Comment: @encore2097 The `\<` means the beginning of a word, whereas `\>` means the end of a word.  In Vim, searching pattern syntax follows grep's basic pattern syntax (mostly), which is why we need `\+` instead of `+` for **more than one occurrence**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
:s/array\[.\{-}\]/atoi(&)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't really say what RegEx engine you are using but if I had to guess it may be that this particular engine doesn't like the "non-greedy" qualifier.  So let's try the regex eleminating the non-greedy qualifier and using a character class of "not closing square bracket" in place of the non-greedy ".*?". Try this instead:

array[([^]]*)]

Comment: I'm using the default for Vim. I didn't know there were multiple, I thought reg ex was a standard -- thanks for letting me know. The regex you provided results in no matches.